# Getting System.DllNotFoundException when deploying to production machine

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce

I'm deploying a WPF ClickOnce application which uses a 3rd party dll written in VC++ and a 3rd party C#  dll for accessing this C++ library. I have the Visual Studio solutions to each of these components and I've built them both with Release/x86 configuration.

My application is set to Release as well however, when I deploy the app to a machine (which does not have Visual Studio) I get System.DllNotFoundException and it says it can't find the c# dll.  I've checked that all required files are present in the "Application Files" directory of the deployed machine.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't they be in the executable's directory on the deployed machine? Make sure they are marked as "Include" rather than "Data File".

Comment: yes, both the c++ .dll and the c# .dll are in the same folder as the executable and they are both marked as Include/Required

Comment: I should also add that I built the 3rd party components in VS 2010 while my application is VS2008. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: You can't get the C++ runtime DLLs deployed with ClickOnce.  That will have to be a 'prerequisite', I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Almost always, in similar cases I had in the past, it was that I forgot to include the Microsoft Visual C++ **CRT** DLLs.

They are included in your Visual Studio installation somewhere similar to

```
c:/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio .net 10/vc/redist/...
```

Usually, I simply copy the DLLs (and the manifest file, too if you are below VS 10.0) to the folder where my executable is being stored.

Since I use "normal" installers, I'm not sure whether this is also applicable to ClickOnce.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Uwe.  I moved the CRT .dlls to the same folder as the executable however I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Uwe...I was able to solve the problem by installing the VS 2010 C++ redist (which I found out is a dependency for the 3rd party dll) to the problem machine..Are you saying that I can get around installing the redist by simply adding the 2 CRT dlls to the executable's folder?

Comment: @Jon E - The CRT are just one of the components. Others _may_ include the ATL and MFC libraries. For me, it was always enough to simply copy the DLLs to the executable's folder, I never needed any redist setup.

Comment: If you have a mix of VS2010 and VS2008 it _may_ be required to deploy the C++ libraries for V9 and V10. Also please pay attention to the DEBUG and RELEASE versions of the C++ libraries and the processor type (x86 or x64). Both of these conditions must match with your DLL.

Comment: Thanks Uwe: I was able to get around the redist issue by compiling the 3rd party c++ dll with visual studio 2008 which removed the dependency on VS2010 c++ redist.  It is now dependent on the vc++ 9 libraries.  I haven't had any issues yet deploying to the client machines.